# User given EDIT permission on item trough workflow can't edit this item

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions, item-level-permissions

In Sharepoint Online we have a list with items that have Item-level permissions set like this
[image]

When the user sets a manager of this item we need to make this item editable to selected manager. I'm doing this using Sharepoint Designer Workflow (2010 with impersonation step) by adding EDIT permission to selected manager.
But even if the user is visible on permissions list with correctly set permissions he can't edit this Item. 
We get `Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.` error.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, you need to set Item-level permissions like this:
[image]

Comment: I think this will give the option to edit any item on a list? The requirement is that only creator and person set as operation manager can edit the item (+ admins of course). It can be changes of course to allow edit by workflow but I need to block access for other users than specified.

Comment: To achieve this, you could add a permission level the same as edit permission level but disable the "Edit Items" permission.Grant users this permission. Then in the workflow, add edit permission to the creator and the manager.

Comment: Exactly the way I needed that. Thank you for pointing in the right direction. I changed Item-level permissions to Create and edit all items Then disabled access to edit items for regular users by removing `Contribute` level permission and creating `Add only` permission level. Now workflow is assigning `Edit` permissions per item only for set users.

Answer (score 0):

The `Contribute` and `Edit` permission levels (role definitions) are not sufficient to bypass the Write Security setting. The `Design` role should contain the necessary base permissions (don't remember whether `Approve Items` or `Cancel Checkout`).

Comment: But adding that on item level not working and when I add this to a group on list level it gives access to edit all item while I want just this one shared item to be available fo edit.